# Handshake alert: Unrecognized_name Liberty Profile

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

I am building a Java EE web application that has a component that connects to a remote server through REST. Unfortunately this server has some problems with the SSL certificates atm which isn't getting fixed until a later date.

From what I found on google is that I should disable SNI on the JVM to temporary "fix" the issue of the handshake alert error, but I don't know how you do this on Websphere Liberty Profile.
Anyone know how to do this or knows a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false`. In Liberty, you can put that in your $servername/jvm.options

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.70.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/customization.html

> jsse.enableSNIExtension system property. Server Name Indication (SNI)
>   is a TLS extension, defined in RFC 4366. SNI enables TLS connections
>   to virtual servers, in which multiple servers for different network
>   names are hosted at a single underlying network address. Some very old
>   SSL/TLS vendors might not support SSL/TLS extensions. In this case,
>   set this property to false to disable the SNI extension.

Comment: Ok this fixed it a bit. Seems that I get another error now, but this has been solved